# Is there a way to "inject" a variable into a method in php?

Tags: php, code-injection

```
Class Foo {
   public function bar() {
     echo $a;
   }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$b = "Hello world";
/* here inject somehow $b into $foo->bar() */
$foo->bar(); //prints "Hello world"
$b = "I <3 php!";
$foo->bar(); //keeps printing "Hello world"
```

Is there a way to do something similar in php without passing the variable $b to the method bar() as a parameter or to the class constructor?? Nor I want to use global variables.

**EDIT 1:**
For who's asking why I want to do something so stange: it would be nice for me to do something like this...

```
class Controller {
   /**
   * @post(name="address", type="email", required="true")
   */
   public function foo() {
       do_something_with($address);
       //$address is equal to $_POST['address'] and have been checked
   }
}
```

**EDIT 2:**
I'm not looking for how to implement annotations in php. There should already be annotation implementations out there. Given I know how to declare my own annotations, I would like to know if is it possible to "magically" declare and initialize a variable inside a method

Comment: Why do you want to do this? And the answer is no.

Comment: Can you explain more about the context in which you want to do this? It seems like a strange thing to do in general.

Comment: This is definitely not something that should be possible, nor should it be attempted. If you explain what you're trying to achieve, there is certainly a better way.

Comment: Yes its possible .... Write your own parser ... :)

Comment: I saw there are annotation implementations for php, so I could implement an hypothetical @post...but I don't know if it's possible to "inject" variable inside methods.

Comment: If you don't mind you can use this http://codepad.org/Us79cGeA

Answer (score 2):

**No** there isn't. Even if it was possible, what you are asking for would be a serious anti-pattern that should be avoided. It just reminds me of superglobals.

The closest thing that you could use which would be useful, would be to use the **singleton pattern** in order to create a "registry" object that stores your variables. However, it's recommended to use [dependency injection](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/11/what-is-dependency-injection) for passing around dependant objects

You could then "load up" your registry singleton with the variables, and then get the instance  inside of your object to access what you need.

### Using a Singleton Registry Class

For an extremely simple [example of how a singleton registry this might work](http://codepad.org/CShVYMuM):

```
<?php
class Registry
{
    private static $items = array();
    private static $instance;

    private function __construct(){}
    private function __clone(){}

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if( !isset( self::$instance ) )
        {
            self::$instance = new Registry();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }    


    public function __set( $key, $item )
    {
        self::$items[ $key ] = $item;
    }

    public function __get( $key )
    {
        if( isset ( self::$items[ $key ] ) )
        {
            return self::$items[ $key ];
        }
    }

    public function getAll()
    {
        return self::$items;
    }
}
?>
```

You could then load up your registry... and access the items in a similar manner.

```
<?php

$registry = Registry::getInstance();
$registry->foo = "bar";
```

Comment: Seriously overcomplicating the use of class variables here.

Comment: Cheers for the down vote Seth :) I'm sure my 10 minutes of writing this detailed answer deserved it.

Comment: sorry about the points.  But all the guy wants is class variables, and everyone is telling him it's impossible.  You method would work, but only because it uses data stored in a class.  So why invent a new class to store the data for a different class?

Comment: My answer is correct. He said himself, "Is there a way to do something similar in php without passing the variable $b to the method bar() as a parameter or to the class constructor?". What he is looking for is a registry. If he wanted to use mutator and accessors, then he would have said that he is happy to use getters and setters.

Comment: You might be right, he might want it to work by magic.  I guess we could ask him.  But if he truly doesn't want to set the variable AT ALL, why would he want to set it in your other class method?  Like I said, overcomplicating the fact that it must be set somewhere.

Comment: Also, I revoted you for the positive.  Your answer works.  But I'm still downvoting all the "IMPOSSIBURR" answers.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could go crazy with PHP's [Reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) mechanism. Get the doc comment of the current class with [`ReflectionClass::getDocComment()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getdoccomment.php) *inside* your method and then try to access the global variable of the same name, along this line:

```
/**
 * Use `$a`
 */
Class Foo {
   public function bar() {
     $rc = new ReflectionClass('Foo');
     $docstr = $rc->getDocComment();
     // here we extract the value "a" from above's comment "Use `$a`":
     $varname = preg_replace('/.*`\$([a-z_]+)`.*/s', '$1', $docstr);
     global $$varname;
     echo $$varname;
   }
}

$a = 'Hi there';
$cls = new Foo();
$cls->bar(); // echos "Hi there"
```

but quite frankly, this looks as if it would do more harm than good, and IMHO you should re-consider your initial approach.

Comment: This is turning into a fun question.  Lots of creativity in the answering.

Comment: I like the ingenuinty of this. The question kind of reminds of interview questions like multiply two numbers without using * or +.

Comment: I thought it won't be something straightforward...I think this is a good answer, but it ends using global variables which I prefer to avoid. Thank you, btw.

Comment: OP says `Nor I want to use global variables.` what the hell this is a nice answer +1

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not. You need to pass the value through the regular channels.

<sub>(Of course there are always more or less involved ways to hack around the runtime and overwrite values in memory, but this is not something you want to do as part of a regular PHP script.)</sub>

Comment: +1, I misread... I thought he was including the option to use the parameter in the constructor.

Comment: This is not true, folks.  He wants to do normal OO things, he just doesn't know how to ask.

Comment: @Seth And you have surmised this how? He's explictly mentioning the class constructor and function parameters, which makes me think he understands those things...

Comment: @deceze but he also mentioned changing the variable outside the class and having the class's data stay the same.  So, he wants class instances.

Comment: Now that I think about it, regular channels is correct.  And there are so many options!

Answer (score 1):

You pretty much ruled out all possibilities to access a variable outside a class.

The answer then is no.

Comment: He didn't rule out using a class variable.

Answer (score 0):

Not with scalars, but it would work with objects and arrays.

```
class Foo {

    protected $arr;
    public function __construct(&$arr) {
        $this->arr =& $arr;
    }

    public function bar()
    {
        echo $this->arr[0] . "\n";
    }
}

$var = array(0 => 'test');
$foo = new Foo($var);

$foo->bar(); // test

$var[0] = 'test2';
$foo->bar(); // test2
```

It's not a good pattern to use usually. The only time I've used it is replacing a dependency on `$_SESSION` variables (in a VERY old system, please don't kill me) with an object.

Answer (score -2):

**Edit:** Congratulations, detractors:  My answer was not the intent of the OP.

What you are asking is a basic part of OO.  You want data encapsulation within your object.  The purpose of objects is not to be a function parking lot.  Objects are supposed to contain data, too.

So use a setter:

```
Class Foo {

    private $a;

    //no construction needed, if you don't want to set values there
    //or...if you do:
    public function __construct(){  // no variables passed to constructor
        $this->a = $_POST['a'];     // variable initialized anyway!
    }

    public function set_a($a){
        $this->a = $a;
    }
    public function bar() {
        echo $this->a;
    }
}
```

and then:

```
$foo = new Foo();
$foo->bar();  // prints that post value
$foo->set_a("Hello World");
$foo->bar();  // prints Hello World.
```

Comment: hahaha +1 for "function parking lot"

Comment: @prodigitalson yeah, well, there seems to be a wealth of people who think that way answering this question.

Comment: this code does not work!

Comment: @JvdBerg It needs the rest of its class definition in order to work, if that's what you mean.  Allow me to write that.

Comment: @Seth Seems to me the OP is pretty much looking for some "magical" way to set the value of a variable directly inside a method without passing variables any way at all; no setters, no parameters, no properties. Nobody is thinking about function parking lots.

Comment: `echo $a; // undefined variable`

Comment: @deceze  Well, the guy asked about setting a value inside a class.  That's not wrong in any way, as long as classes contain data with accessors.

Comment: @JvdBerg  you were right, I edited that line.

Comment: Well, now it is not a valid answer to the question anymore. You pass the variable to the class.

Comment: @JvdBerg he didn't say he didn't want to pass it to the class, he said he didn't want to pass it to the method or the class constructor.

Comment: So basically, "we told you so"? :P But we've still been downvoted? :(

Comment: @deceze It tells me I can't change my vote unless you edit your answer .  But I would if you want.  Somehow I doubt I'll get my downvotes removed :(